# Can Flex 4.5/4.6 (AIR) integrate with FluorineFX?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, fluorinefx

I would like to create a mobile application targeting android platform.
I am planning to use FLEX 4.5/ 4.6 (AIR) and MSSQL as its database.
Can FLEX 4.5/4.6 connects to a MSSQL 2005 database using FLUORINEFX?

I have created a webbased application using FLEX 3(FLASH PLAYER) that connects to a MSSQL 2005 database using FLUORINEFX.

I am not sure about FLEX 4.5/4.6 (AIR) intregration with FLUORINEFX?
Please guide me on how i get about this. Could not find the right information for me to move forward or maybe im using the wrong keywords during my search in google.

Answer (score 2):

Fluorine FX is always implemented server-side and most often used to setup a remoting service.

Any Flex/flash/ajax/.. client should be able to consume this service.

Try reading the documentation: http://www.fluorinefx.com/docs/fluorine/index.html

Look for a section called "Calling web services from Flex".
 
The same principles should apply regardless the version of the Flex SDK you are using.

Cheers